# What does "Expect a bitemporal response" mean?

Tags: tenet

> Ives: We drop in, clear LZs for Blue Team evacuation. We make our way
> into the city proper. These buildings are abandoned, but we learned
> there is a turnstile. **Expect a bitemporal response**.

What does "Expect a bitemporal response" mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Within the worldbuilding of Tenet, soldiers and combat personnel are capable of moving through time in two different directions, forward (as we normally do) and backwards. Ives is warning his troops that because of the presence of a (time-)"*turnstile*" on site, that there is likely to be a response that follows the attack but also one that *precedes it*.

To counter this probable advantage, Ives and the Protagonist arrange for their own '[*temporal pincer movement*](https://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/tenet-explained-inversion-temporal-pincer-movements-timeline-plot/)', with some of their soldiers reversing their temporal direction (using the turnstile captured in the airport) and attacking from the future while their second wave, moving forward through time (and now acting on information gleaned from the future attack) attacks normally.